MicroCloud install issue... unable to ping virtual router in OVN
MicroCloud install was successful and can ping between instances, but no egress or ingress access. Requesting help with next steps to troubleshoot, confirm root cause, remediate, etc... any assistance would be much appreciated.
Followed this guide and all steps were successful up to 7.4, “Make sure that you can ping the virtual router within OVN.”
https://canonical-microcloud.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/microcloud/tutorial/get_started/
Output of various commands below…
microcloud-01:~$ ping -c 5 172.16.2.100
PING 172.16.2.100 (172.16.2.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
— 172.16.2.100 ping statistics -
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4103ms


$ lxc network show default
name: default
description: “”
type: ovn
managed: true
status: Created
config:
  bridge.mtu: “1442”
  ipv4.address: 10.217.129.1/24
  ipv4.nat: “true”
  ipv6.address: fd42:26b3:d263:222a::1/64
  ipv6.nat: “true”
  network: UPLINK
  volatile.network.ipv4.address: 172.16.2.100
used_by:
  /1.0/instances/u1
  /1.0/instances/u2
  /1.0/profiles/default

locations:
  microcloud-01
  microcloud-03
  microcloud-02


$ lxc network show UPLINK
name: UPLINK
description: “”
type: physical
managed: true
status: Created
config:
  ipv4.gateway: 172.16.2.1/24
  ipv4.ovn.ranges: 172.16.2.100-172.16.2.254
  volatile.last_state.created: “false”
used_by:
  /1.0/networks/default
locations:
  microcloud-01
  microcloud-03
  microcloud-02


$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 52:54:00:4d:f5:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 172.16.1.11/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global enp1s0
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe4d:f585/64 scope link
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 52:54:00:47:7d:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether a6:90:ec:49:ee:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1442 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 62:75:01:ce:f6:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: genev_sys_6081: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65000 qdisc noqueue master ovs-system state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether ea:29:6a:c6:d3:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet6 fe80::20d0:16ff:fee6:187/64 scope link
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: lxdovn1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether 32:65:88:ec:04:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: vethf5c8a706@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1442 qdisc noqueue master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether d2:ad:26:c3:f3:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0


$ ip r
default via 172.16.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto static
172.16.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.11


$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
This is the network config written by ‘subiquity’
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.11/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 4.2.2.2
          - 8.8.8.8
        search: 
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.16.1.1
    enp2s0:
      accept-ra: false
      dhcp4: false
  link-local: 
version: 2


Removed all snaps and used the latest "edge" versions and voila!  All other steps from tutorial worked fine... here are the commands I ran on the three nodes to get the microcloud to complete initialization:
snap remove lxd microceph microovn microcloud
snap install lxd --channel=latest/edge
snap install microceph --channel=latest/edge
snap install microovn --channel=latest/edge
snap install microcloud --channel=latest/edge
sudo snap refresh lxd microceph microovn microcloud --cohort="+"
sudo snap refresh --hold lxd microceph microovn microcloud

FYI, microcloud init fails when selecting "yes" for 'remote-fs' but works if select "no"... need to troubleshoot further for that option.
BTW, installed on three Dell PE 1950 III servers with 40GB RAM, 8 cores and SSDs.  Old but good hardware for a home lab.
